# removing class or element with id with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, removeclass

I'm trying to remove a div from the page (preferably prevent it from loading at all) but for now i'm settling on removing it after the page loads.

i tried out these lines of codes here on jsfiddle and it works. and the '#content_gallery' div gets removed.

http://jsfiddle.net/FRYsJ/9/

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function(){$('#content_gallery').remove();});

</script>
```

but when i apply it on the head of my test website. it doesnt remove the div with the id specified. i also tried removing other divs with other id labels

test site: http://stage.bravo-company.info/luchatest/category/gallery/

i also tried:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){        
        $('#content').remove();

 });
```

and

```
$(function(){
    $('#content_gallery').remove();
});
```

any ideas? could it be a case of jquery conflict? im not sure how to confirm this.

here is the test site: http://stage.bravo-company.info/luchatest/category/gallery/

Comment: I couldn't find any element with id = `content_gallery` in the test site.

Comment: on your site (nice site btw) there is no tag to be found with id="content_gallery" ?

Comment: Anyway, looking with Firebug it tells this: `TypeError: $(...).ready is not a function`.

Comment: @Elger sorry my bad, i was supposed to link to the gallery. here: http://stage.bravo-company.info/luchatest/category/gallery/

Comment: Don't repost your question; your old question has received enough answers to understand what should be done.

Comment: @LenielMacaferi here's the correct link : http://stage.bravo-company.info/luchatest/category/gallery/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is another JavaScript library that is conflicting with `jQuery` on your site. The correct way of fixing this issue would be to use [`jQuery.noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.noConflict();

    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
        $(function(){
            $('#content_gallery').remove();
        });
    });

    // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

Comment: thanks this did the trick. cheers. i used "$j("#content_gallery").remove();"

Comment: The `$.noConflict()` seems superfluous; the code would work without it.

Answer (score 0):

It is a case conflict

use

```
jquery(document).ready(function(){jquery('#content_gallery').remove();});
```